# How can I change the iOS App Store Country on my iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, accounts

When I try to download any app on my iPhone 5, I receive the following message:

> Account not in this store. Your account is not valid for use in the Swiss store. You  must switch to the the US store before purchasing.

How do I switch from the Swiss store to the US store?

Answer (score 27):

On your iPhone 5 follow these steps:

1. Tap on the App Store icon in your Home Screen.
2. Tap on Featured on the bottom left corner of screen.
3. Scroll all the way to the bottom where your Apple ID info is.  Tap on it.
4. Tap View Apple ID, you may have to enter your password.
5. Once the page loads Change your country/Region to United States.

   - Must not have any credits in your account
   - Must have a valid payment method for the desired country - there is no longer a none option.

Comment: "Please note that you need a valid method of payment for the new country" :'(

Comment: You don't need a valid method of payment, you can select 'none' and still download free apps BUT you will need to enter a valid address for the country such as Mc Donalds ;)